# Script works with keyboard, but only inconsistent with responsebuttons

Tags: matlab, psychtoolbox

In my script I want to record responses (keyboard <kbd>r</kbd> or response button click) while I show different stimuli (`image1`, `image2`). The loop (trial) always shows `image1`, then `image2` and stores the recorded time of the click as we need the response times. One can click during `image1` or `image2` but only once per trial.

Recording works during both images with keyboard presses. However, it only records button presses during `image1`, not `image2`. Therefore, the problem is not that responses are not recorded, the buttons work actually.

I tried: Using different Response Buttons, using mouse as response button. When I click the response button, it writes `r` in the commandline, also during `image1` it is collected.

How can I get the response button to work when showing `image2`?

```matlab
startOfTrial = GetSecs;

% Stimulus presentation
    Screen('DrawTexture', myScreen, image1)
    [VBLTimestamp StimulusOnsetTime1] = Screen('Flip', myScreen);

    % Response recording
    [keyIsDown, responseTime1, keyCode] = KbCheck; % saves whether a key has been pressed, seconds and the key which has been pressed.
    while keyCode(BUTTON) == 0 
        [keyIsDown, responseTime1, keyCode] = KbCheck;
        if responseTime1 - StimulusOnsetTime1 >= stimDuration
            Screen('DrawTexture', myScreen, image2);
            [VBLTimestamp StimulusEndTime1]  = Screen('Flip', myScreen);
            if responseTime1 - StimulusOnsetTime1 >= stimDuration + ISI
                break
            end
        end
    end

    if responseTime1 - StimulusOnsetTime1 < stimDuration
        WaitSecs(stimDuration - (responseTime1 - StimulusOnsetTime1));
        [VBLTimestamp StimulusEndTime1]  = Screen('Flip', myScreen); 
    end

    % Checking correctness
    if keyCode(BUTTON) == 1
        RT(trial) = (responseTime1 - StimulusOnsetTime1)*1000; % Converts to milliseconds
        response(trial) = 1;
        if trialList(2, trial) == 1
            correctness(trial) = 1; % Hit
        else
            correctness(trial) = 2; % False Alarm
        end
    else
        response(trial) = 0;
        if trialList(2, trial) == 1
            correctness(trial) = 3; % Miss
        else
            correctness(trial) = 4; % Correct rejection
        end
    end

    c = correctness(trial)

    t2 = GetSecs;
    % Presenting blank screen for remaining time
    if t2 - StimulusEndTime1 < ISI
       Screen('DrawTexture', myScreen, image2);
       Screen('Flip', myScreen);
       WaitSecs(ISI - (t2 - StimulusEndTime1));
    end
```

Comment: What is the 'image2', the cross texture you draw via Screen('DrawTexture', myScreen, cross);?

Comment: I did change the variable names to image1 and image2 to match it to the question. I hope this clarifies it. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you're only polling for a single button, the value of BUTTON. How are you determining that you're only registering a press during image1 and not image2, via the logged response time?

Comment: I record the time the button is pressed, therefore I can tell that only presses during image1 (500 msec) are recorded. I also tested this by pressing only during image1 or image2 and then checking the log file.

Comment: While you didn't provide all values needed to reproduce this example (stimDuration, ISI, etc.) the existing code seems to be working as you described, a keyboard button press is captured during either the first or second stimulus with the appropriate response time. Is the keyboard button you're having issue with, or a mouse click?